# Recursive function

Tags: functions, recursion

I'm trying to define a function that takes in a list (a1,a2,a3,...,an) and spits out (a1^1, a2^2, a3^3,...,an^n) using recursion. 
So far I've tried a lot of different things that don't work, and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Try `list^Range[Length[list]]`.

Comment: Works, thanks. how about a function that takes in (a1,a2,a3,...,an) and spits out an extended version (a1,a1, a2,a2,a3,a3,..,an,an)

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework so I'll only offer a hint. I assume you have already learned how to write a recursive function that would, for example, divide each element by 3. This new problem requires the function keep track of how many times it has been called. So add one extra argument to the function. Imagine on your first call you make that argument=1. And each recursive call increments the value of that argument. That should be enough of a hint.

Comment: @Bill FWIW this problem does not *require* that one *directly* keep track of how many times the function is called; the recursion itself can build a structure with a shape that tracks this inherently. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Using *Mathematica*'s destructuring and list multiplication:

```
f[{a_, b___}] := Join[{a}, {b}*f[{b}]]

f[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]
```

> ```
> {a1, a2^2, a3^3, a4^4, a5^5}
> ```

In the comments you mention a second problem:

```
f2[{a_, b___}] := Join[{a, a}, f2[{b}]]
f2[{}] := {}

f2[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]
```

> ```
> {a1, a1, a2, a2, a3, a3, a4, a4, a5, a5}
> ```

Though practically this is better done in *Mathematica* without recursion:

```
Riffle[#, #] & @ {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
```